# How do you restart Swift Command Line code from the beginning?

Tags: swift, command-line-interface

I am new to swift and I am currently trying to build a basic number
guessing game using Xcode's command line tool. I have been able to complete the game but I am not able to find out how to restart the game so that the user can play again after winning or losing. Any advice?

Comment: Why not use a loop?

Answer (score 1):

Given that no details or code were given, i'll say you may use a loop. You probably are storing the game state in variables. When the game reaches the end, the loop should restart, restoring all game data to the initial state. If you have any doubts, read this section of the Swift documentation about control flow (it has examples with games, yay):

https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/ControlFlow.html

Answer (score 1):

Felipe Borges got started but I wanted to provide a concrete example on how one might design such a game:

```
var playAgain = true
repeat {
    print("The game starts!")

    // The user plays
    // Response is a game-state variable
    let response = readLine()

    print("The game is over yay!")

    print("ask the user whether to play again?")
    playAgain = false // whatever the user does goes here
} while playAgain
```

The two most important things to keep in mind are the loop and the game state. The game state should be scoped inside a function or loop so that the next iteration of the game starts over with new values. In my example, there are no variables pertaining to specific game states outside of the `repeat {} while` loop, so each iteration starts fresh (the `response` variable being the example here).